# How to achieve dropdown inside Xtype Multifield in AEM, which populates textfield on click of values inside dropdown

Tags: aem

I have a scenario where I have a dropdown inside multifield on click of values inside dropdown text field and another multifield should appear. How to achieve this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your implementation -

1. Nested multifield - To get this working refer to AEM blog [here](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/03/aem-6-sp2-touch-ui-coral-ui-nested-multi-multifield.html) and helpx article [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/nested_multifield.html)
2. Hide/show multifield based on the value selected in a dropdown

For touch UI refer to 
1) To get 1) working refer to AEM blog [here](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/03/aem-6-sp2-touch-ui-coral-ui-nested-multi-multifield.html) and helpx article [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/nested_multifield.html)
2) To achieve 2) all you have to do is write listeners, for this refer to AEM documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/components-touch-optimized.html#Listeners%20in%20a%20custom%20client%20library)

For Classic UI - 
1) Refer to blogpost [here](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/06/aem-61-classic-ui-nested-composite-multifield-panel.html)
2) Concept for hide/show in ClassicUI will also involve writing a listener with `selectionchanged` event and `onload` event refer to [selectionchanged event is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089385/selectionchanged-event-is-not-working) for example